# Can i open file in TEXTPAD in same tab instead of a separate instance of textpad

Tags: multiple-instances, textpad

Ive recently got this computer & have installed textpad.

Its going Ok, however i have found a few problems.

1) If im looking at FILE1.txt, I decide i want to open FILE2.txt - it opens in textpad ok, however its in a separate instance of Textpad.

Is it possible to open the 2nd file in the SAME/existing instance, but as a separate TAB within textpad ?

2) If i open FILE1.txt,  it opens another instance of textpad. Now I have 3 THREE instances of textpad open,  FILE1.txt, FILE2.txt  and FILe1.txt (two versions of FILE1.txt)

Is it possible to re-open my existing version of a file if i have it open ?

Answer (score 2):

Both of your issues can be resolved with the same change in setting.

- In Textpad go to **Configure**
- Then choose **Preferences**
- Make sure you're on the **General** tab
- Look for the checkbox labeled `Allow multiple instances to run` and uncheck it
- Click **Apply** and close out of that window
- Now whenever you open a new txt file it will open as an additional tab in your existing Textpad instances

[image: gif of setting being changed]

---

---

- Also as a result of the change you made above, whenever you go to open a file that is already open in Textpad it will not create a new instance or even a new tab. It will just take you to the tab of the file that is already open.